# Get last 3 digits in unix timestamp Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am getting the current date and time in timestamp as below:

```
var timeNow = (new Date()).getTime();
var firsthalf;
var last3digits;
```

I want to divide the timestamp I got and store it in different variables

For example
if I got may var timeNow as **1499668369988**
The **var firsthalf** will have the value of **1499668369** and the **var** **last3digits** will have **988**

Appreciate you helping me with it. Thank you.

Comment: for last 3 digits you can do timenow%1000 and for first half parseInt(timenow/1000)

Comment: Note that parseInt expects a string argument. It's much faster to just do: (timeNow/1000)|0 . See also my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

very simple

```
var timeNow = (new Date()).getTime().toString();
var firsthalf=timeNow.substr(0,10);
var last3digits=timeNow.substr(10);

//or
var last3digits=timeNow.substr(-3);
```

Comment: i would go for this one since it conveys meaning the most (who reads modulus operators naturally?)

Comment: Don't use string functions on numbers, it's so much slower than a numerical solution like mine or IvoP's.

Comment: I would write `var last3digits=timeNow.substr(-3);` as more straightforward variant.

Comment: this is the correct one suited for my need. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String()`, `String.prototype.slice()`, `+` operator to convert string to number

```
var timeNow = (new Date()).getTime();
var firsthalf = +String(timeNow).slice(0, 10);
var last3digits = +String(timeNow).slice(-3);
```

Comment: No need to waste computing power by doing this using strings. Use a purely numerical solution like mine or IvoP's.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
var first = (timeNow / 1000) | 0; // the "|0" part looses the fraction
var last3digits = timeNow % 1000;
```

timeNow is a number, no need to use string slicing ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried this but this losses the first digit if the first digit is 0. check this http://jsfiddle.net/8d3hxyfn/

Comment: @toodleoo You should have given more information as to the application of the two results. Apparently, you want to use them as strings. If you treat them as numbers (which they are) that leading zero is insignificant.

Answer (score 0):

As it is about numbers, a numeric approach:

```
var timeNow = (new Date()).getTime();
var last3digits = timeNow % 1000;
var firsthalf = (timeNow - last3digits) / 1000;
```